# Help regarding closing reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just review-closed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483935/determine-the-resultant-of-the-two-forces-applied) question as off-topic with sub-reason being
*"This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center"*.

Another possible sub-reason was that it belongs on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). In spite of this, since I've heard that Physics SE does not welcome such questions, I decided to choose that the question simply didn't belong on MSE.

I suppose there might be people who disagree with closing this question in particular. Despite this, it is conceivable that there might be similar questions which should definitely be closed as off-topic. 
Regarding the aforementioned questions, what sub-reason should be chosen: $$\text{doesn't belong on MSE} \color{grey}{\text{ or }} \text{belongs on Physics SE }?$$

Comment: By the way, could it be, by any chance, that Physics SE is divided about wether to welcome such questions or not, like MSE is regarding PSQs without effort shown?

Comment: Regarding the question in the comment above, it appears that physics.SE has achieved a much greater consensus on this issue.  Consider the following meta.physics threads: [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/29205), [Physics SE should emphasis on problem solving](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4308/29205).

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks. Apparently I chose the right reason.

Comment: The physics site is notorious for over-active moderation, which has led to acrimonious discussions on their meta, the self-banning of the #1 contributor, and other problems.  Some of it is particular to the subject, some is the moderators there, and some is legacy from the collapse of the theoretical physics SE site (from which the ruling caste of physics.SE is drawn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relatively recent meta.SO question seemed to touch on this, and it seems that simple voting to close as off topic (unless you are fairly knowledgeable about about the proposed destination site) is the best policy.

> [Close as off topic, flag to migrate, or both?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193815/214632)

An additional option would be to flag the question stating potential migration to a specific site as a reason.  We are able to easily ping the moderators for a specific SE site, and thereby inquire whether specific questions would be welcomed at another SE site.  But please do not overuse this.